# Solution to the recommended 2" roof gap for Hardie siding

Tags: roof, waterproofing, siding, flashing

So, I'm aware that Hardie recommends a 2" gap between the roof line when installing around a dormer. However, I find this gap to be rather extreme and makes for a strange look. I have also noticed many houses with Hardie siding do not have this big of a gap on them. I do want to follow the recommended practice, but I am wondering if there are any ways to make this detail look nicer. Is it ok to butt pvc trim tight to the roofline and then run the siding up from that? Or perhaps I could paint a piece of flashing the same color as the siding to bridge the 2" gap. Not sure if there is a good solution to this or not.

Comment: Sure, but those are design decisions that are off topic here. You can do whatever you like as long as the cement board is elevated for moisture protection.

Comment: A better fix might be to just use color-coordinating flashing in the gap. 2" isn't really that large when viewed from the ground.